# Evernote cocoa SDK not compiling for ios5

Tags: ios, sdk, evernote

I am implementing an iOS app for a customer and i want to include a Evernote sync function to store some information as notes on the users Evernote account.

The goal would be to create a notebook (if it doesnt exist yet) on the users Evernote account, and store some notes there/ read the existing notes to update the contents on my app.

I downloaded the newest Evernote SDK (1.20) from the developers site and tried to start playing with it. What i did:

- Imported **cocoa/src/edam** & **cocoa/src/thrift** folders in a new group of my xcode project.
- Set the **-fno-objc-arc** compilation Flag on all those files to avoid getting ARC related errors.
- Imported the Evernote.m/Evernote.h files to try to start using their functions. Just to go step by step.

But as soon as i try to compile the App  get tons of errors mostly coming from the **edam/Types.h** file. I attach you 2 screenshots for clarity.

[image: Screen1]
[image: Screen2]

Has somebody had the same problems?
Has somebody integrated Evernote in his/her iOS App?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've bumped into some ARC-incompatibilities in our SDK. There's an [unreleased patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1340) for the Thrift Objective-C code generator and runtime that claims to make a single codebase that works with both ARC and non-ARC projects. I made a version of our Obj-C wrappers using the patched generator; you can download it from http://evernote.s3.amazonaws.com/api/evernote-objc-arc-test.zip. Replace the cocoa/src directory of our SDK with the contents of the ZIP, remove the -fno-objc-arc flags from your project, and let me know how it goes. I can't vouch for this code yet, so don't deploy it in a production app. We'll try to finalize this next week.

Comment: Hi Seth, Thanks a lot for your quick answer and support. The code you provided seem to work perfectly, i imported it on my project and tested it to upload a note to my sandbox account, everything worked well since i could see the note through the web interface. I hope you guys make this code officially available so we can use it in our production apps.

Thanks again and happy new year.